# Magento Rest API

Tags: magento-1, rest-api, oauth, postman

I want to use the Magento rest API for my application, when I will call the API from postman tool at that time there showing me error as per below:

> oauth_problem=parameter_absent&oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_callback

Here are my settings in PostMan Toolbox:

[image]

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

Try to check is the `oauth_callback` parameter exists in yours Authorization header. From the [docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html):

> The following request parameters should be present in the
>   Authorization header:
>
> oauth_callback - an URI to which the Service Provider will redirect the resource owner (user) after the authorization is
>   complete.

From the [OAuth wiki](http://wiki.oauth.net/w/page/12238543/ProblemReporting):

> parameter_absent: a required parameter wasn't received. In this case,
>   the response SHOULD also contain an oauth_parameters_absent parameter
>   (described below).

Comment: it's not working into my site. Also, I have tried same.

Comment: @H.K.Suthar Can you add the request parameters (as strings) to your question?

Comment: Yes, I have added as string.